# Template specialization of clearing std::queue with other std containers

Tags: c++, templates

I created a function `Clear` that receives a varied number of parameters, and clears those containers

```
inline void Clear() {}
template <class First, class ...Rest>
void Clear(First&& first, Rest&&... rest)
{
    std::forward<First>(first).clear();
    Clear(std::forward<Rest>(rest)...);
}
```

So I can use it to clear most std containers of any type, like std::set, std::unordered_set, std::map, etc.
But `std::queue` doesn't have a `.clear()` method, so I tried to specialize it

```
template <typename T>
void Clear(std::queue<T>& q)
{
    std::queue<T> empty;
    std::swap(q, empty);
}
```

Calling `Clear` on any std::queue works, but it doesn't integrate with the other Clear function. Obviously I want the variadic argument version of Clear to work with the specialization. Help?
As a curiosity, how does the generated assembly compare with using .clear() in every container, and using this template?

Comment: as an aside if you need to clear your queue you probably don't want to use `std::queue` which is explicitly designed to hide all methods apart from `push`/`pop`, `front`/`back` and `size`/`empty`, use `std::deque` instead

Comment: I see your point, but I also see situations when someone may want to clear an std::queue. In my case, I have a queue of "things to do" in the order they arrive, shared with worker threads, but it's also possible to "cancel" them all, by clearing the queue. Do you think it's worth it to use a deque in this case?

Comment: If you are using `std::queue` you are probably already using a `std::deque`, `std::queue` is just a wrapper, if its limitations don't fit with your use-case just use the underlying container directly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might split iteration and job for one element, something like:

```
template <typename T>
void Clear(std::queue<T>& q) {
    std::queue<T> empty;
    std::swap(q, empty);
}

template <typename C>
void Clear(C& c) {
    c.clear();
}

template <typename ... Ts>
void Clear(Ts&... ts) {
    (Clear(ts), ...);
}
```